# Getting a error in my node js https server

Tags: node.js

I have built a https server and got my certs all there and it seems to find them with no issues. My my issue is that any time I run the code I am getting

```
var proxy = new http_proxy.HttpProxy({
            ^

TypeError: http_proxy.HttpProxy is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Adam.Wolarczuk\Desktop\Projects\nodetest\server.js:11:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

I tried to find the issue on the web but can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
var http_proxy = require ('http-proxy'),
    https = require('https'),
    fs = require('fs');

var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync("privatekey.pem").toString();
var cert        = fs.readFileSync("newcert.pem").toString();

var options = {key: privateKey, cert: cert };

var proxy = new http_proxy.HttpProxy({
    target:{
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8080
}

});

var s =https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
    console.log("Proxying!");
    proxy.proxyRequest(req, res);

});

s.listen(8443);
```

Comment: RTFM https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy#using-https

Answer (score 0):

The docs don't specify your syntax nor the library exports the module you're trying to initialize.
RTFM https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy

**EDIT**

Even though the docs are VERY good, here's an example w/ Proxy over HTTPS node server:

```js
var http_proxy = require ('http-proxy'),
    https = require('https'),
    fs = require('fs');

var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync("privatekey.pem").toString();
var cert        = fs.readFileSync("newcert.pem").toString();

var options = {key: privateKey, cert: cert };

var proxy = httpProxy.createServer({
  ssl: {
    key: privateKey,
    cert
  },
  target: 'https://localhost:9010', // Send it anywhere
  secure: true // Depends on your needs, could be false.
}).listen(443);

var s = https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
    console.log("Proxying!");
    proxy.web(req, res);
});

s.listen(8443);
```

Comment: Hi Sorry dont really know what you are asking for i am still new to this 

I followed this Video from NODE.JS

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dp8-oNMmJMI

Comment: @AdamWolarczuk The video is more than 2 years old. Probably the API changed. Read the documentation.

Comment: Hi i did read it and still cant get it to work, could you please take alook and point me in the right direction